# Sum only consecutive positive numbers and place the sum in a new vector in specific positions (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, indexing

I have the variable P1 (LENGTH= 36) and i want to make the sum of ONLY consecutive positive values and place the sum in a new vector (called "out") in the position that you can see in Figure. If there is only one value you can place it in the same position of P1 and repeat the value below for 8 times. Otherwise, place it in the lowest consecutive positive position and repeat it for 8 times. For the other values of out i want zero. See Figure below. In red there is what I need to calculate.

I tried with the code below, however it gives me out all equal to 0. I tried to fix the problem but I need help.

Thanks in advance!!

[image]

```
lo = P1 > 0;
Dfference = diff([lo(:);0]); 
Ends  = find(Dfference==-1);  % -1 are the positions where a sequence ends
Start = find(Dfference==1)+1; %  1 are the positions where a sequence starts -1

out = zeros(size(P1));
for idx=1:length(Start)
    out(Ends(idx):Ends(idx)+8) = sum(P1(Start(idx):Ends((idx))));
end
```

This is my matrix:

```
P1 = [
39
-2
-2
-2
-2
-2
-2
-2
-2
-2
-2
60
39
-2
-2
-2
-2
-2
-2
-2
-2
-2
-2
60
39
-2
-2
-2
-2
-2
-2
-2
-2
-2
-2
60];
```

Comment: What happens if a postive sequence occurs before the 8 repititions of previous value are completed? Please provide your P1 matrix as text instead so that it may be copy-pasted into MATLAB

Comment: @Sardar Usama thks for your really fast reply! For this kind of data it can't happens. Ok I attached my data, thanks!

Comment: @Sardar Usama how can I do to attach a txt file here?

Comment: Just copy paste the text and format it as code. Please keep it minimal

Comment: `movsum(max(P1,0),[8 0])` will be a good start, then you just need to delete the consecutive non zero value.

Comment: @obchardon thank you very much! How can I do it? This matrix is almost ok!

Comment: @SardarUsama repetitions will be created the same time I will create out, they are not input..